# positionning the boxes

Tags: tables, positioning, rotating

As I have understood latex uses boxes, I thought it would be easy to do what I want as I know how to make these boxes (took me a few hours, but ok).

But no. I can't find the tricks, eventhough I am pretty sure it is possible.

Here is what I want :

On a mini piece of square paper of 7 cm (square for the fun, 7cm is not mandatory, but I can say it's ok, it gives enough room to do wha I want), I want to place a block with name and address on the top left. On the bottom left I want the PGP fingerprint.

On the right side, I want to place the url of my website (placed in a sideways).
[image: sheme to describe my desire]

Here is my current code :

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[height=10cm,width=10cm,margin=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}

\ExplSyntaxOn
 \NewDocumentCommand{\printpgp}{O{}m}
   ............
 \ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{lc}

    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
     Stéphane Guedon\\
     Onsholtvej 186\\
     8260 Viby J, Århus\\

     +45 2071 6010

     stephane@22decembre.eu

     PGP :
     \printpgp{47D6459B2DCEE5C1439C53330403A28B2D8DE8FB}
    \end{minipage} &

    \begin{sideways}
     \url{http://www.22decembre.eu}
    \end{sideways}

  \end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

Please note that the tabular env (and the sideways also) is only a way to get it. I don't know if it's the right solution.

At first I was thinking of a minipage on the left side with two boxes in, one on the top for the address, and one on the bottom for the PGP fingerprint.

But the PGP fing' was never really at the bottom and the sideways did not appears.

Comment: Please, next time add a minimal but *still* working example.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean Fran. If I have a working example, I would not ask for help...

Comment: In a minimal working example (MWE) understand "working" as "compilable" code that show your problem. This should produce a PDF and not produce a compilation error, unless the purpose of the MWE is just show that error. When you changed some part of your preamble by  `............`  we cannot see your boxes problem but a `LaTeX error: Missing \begin{document}` and we must lost time guessing where is the offending code, then wonder what the hell `\printpgp{}` is... At this point the helper tend to move to the next question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here me approach with two minipages. I added colored frames to check visually their size and position.

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage[height=10cm,width=10cm,margin=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\printpgp}{O{}m}
 {
  \par\noindent
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { xxiidecembre/printpgp } { #1 }
  \xxiidecembre_printpgp:n { #2 }
  \par
  \group_end:
 }

\keys_define:nn { xxiidecembre/printpgp }
 {
  font .tl_set:N = \l_xxiidecembre_pgpfont_tl,
  font .initial:n = \ttfamily,
  break .bool_set:N = \l_xxiidecembre_pgpbreak_bool,
  break .initial:n = true,
 }

\tl_new:N \l__xiidecembre_pgp_tl
\int_new:N \l__xxiidecembre_step_int
\int_new:N \l__xxiidecembre_group_int
\cs_new_protected:Npn \xxiidecembre_printpgp:n #1
 {
  \tl_use:N \l_xxiidecembre_pgpfont_tl
  \tl_set:Nn \l__xiidecembre_pgp_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__xiidecembre_pgp_tl { ~ } { }
  \int_compare:nTF { \tl_count:N \l__xiidecembre_pgp_tl = 40 }
   {
    \__xxiidecembre_printpgp:V \l__xiidecembre_pgp_tl
   }
   {
    INVALID~PGP
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xxiidecembre_printpgp:n #1
 {
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    ##1
    \int_incr:N \l__xxiidecembre_step_int
    \int_compare:nT { \l__xxiidecembre_step_int = 4 }
     {
      \int_incr:N \l__xxiidecembre_group_int
      \int_compare:nTF { \l__xxiidecembre_group_int = 5 }
       {
        \bool_if:NTF \l_xxiidecembre_pgpbreak_bool { \\ } { ~ }
       }
       {
        \c_space_tl
       }
      \int_zero:N \l__xxiidecembre_step_int
     }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__xxiidecembre_printpgp:n { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\fboxsep5pt

\begin{document}
\fcolorbox{red!20}{yellow!05}{\begin{minipage}[c][7cm]{\dimexpr7cm-1em}\large
     Stéphane Guedon\\[2ex]
     Onsholtvej 186\\[2ex]
     8260 Viby J, Århus\\[2ex]
     +45 2071 6010\\[2ex]
     stephane@22decembre.eu\\
\vfill
     PGP :
     \printpgp{47D6459B2DCEE5C1439C53330403A28B2D8DE8FB}
    \end{minipage}}%
\fcolorbox{blue!20}{cyan!05}{\begin{minipage}{1em}
\large\begin{turn}{90}
\makebox[7cm][c]{\url{http://www.22decembre.eu}}
\end{turn}
\end{minipage}}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly right that "latex uses boxes". LaTeX is a macro package over TeX and **TeX** uses boxes. I show you the solution where dimensions are set exactly as in your sketch but LaTeX is not used. I used plain TeX and opmac.

```
\input opmac  \nopagenumbers

\sdef{pgs:7x7}{(7,7)cm}  \margins/1 7x7 (5,5,5,5)mm

\newcount\tmpnum
\def\pgp#1{\tmpnum=0 \pgpA #1 {}...}
\def\pgpA#1#2#3#4{\ifx^#1^\unskip\else
   \ifnum\tmpnum=5\par\fi
   \advance\tmpnum by1
   #1#2#3#4
   \expandafter\pgpA\fi}

\parindent=0pt \topskip=0pt

\vglue-.5\baselineskip
\line{\hfill\pdfsave\pdfrotate{90}\llap{\url{http://www.22decembre.eu}}\pdfrestore}
\vskip-.5\baselineskip

Stéphane Guedon\nl
Onsholtvej 186\nl
8260 Viby J, rhus\nl
+45 2071 6010\nl
stephane@22decembre.eu

\vfill
PGP:\par
{\tt\pgp{47D6459B2DCEE5C1439C53330403A28B2D8DE8FB}}

\break \end
```

Comment: Why do you `\input opmac` when only using a small part of its capabilities?

Comment: @PaulGessler Two features are used form OPmac: margins setting and `\pdfrotate{90}`. Why people use LaTeX when they use only small part of its capabilities?

Comment: @PaulGessler And just for comparison: when you need the same functionality in LaTeX, you have to load `geometry.sty` and `rotating.sty`. The first style file loads three else packages with 1710 lines of code in total. The second package loads seven additional packages with 1600 lines in total. Sum: 3300 lines. The whole OPmac package is in one file with only 1700 lines.